# Error : "Call to a member function load() on a non-object "

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I'm trying code like tutorial

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html
But i can't get the same result . Please tell me why my code doesn't work

**My error**:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line 225

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <weblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
                    <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </weblog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <weblog>
                <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
            </weblog>
            <weblog_resource>
                <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <blogpost>
                        <table>blog_posts</table>
                    </blogpost>
                </entities>
            </weblog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

IndexController

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_IndexController extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function testModelAction() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
        echo get_class($blogpost);
        //var_dump($blogpost);
        //echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
        $blogpost->load($params['id']);
        $data = $blogpost->getData();
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Blogpost.php

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a model like in this line:

```
$blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
```

You can not just assume that this works. You have to first of all check the post-condition of that call:

```
$blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
if (!$blogpost) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('Expected Model not available.');
}
```

This will prevent that you run into the error you have as well. It should also give you a hint what has not been properly configured: The model you tried to get.

The solution then is to learn with a step debugger where the configuration for that model is normally taken from.

For example you could have a configuration cache enabled and the system is still running on older configuration where the model didn't exist. Or your configuration is up to date but the model was just not properly configured in it.

---

Next to verifying post-conditions you also need to verify pre-conditions in your case. I mixed the place where the error occured a bit, but thanks to your comment, a pre-condition test similar to the post-condition check I already outlined can be introduced in the load method, see the following example:

```
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
    }

    /**
     * Load object data
     *
     * @param   integer $id
     * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     */
    public function load($id, $field=null)
    {
        $resource =  $this->_getResource();
        if (!$resource) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Resource instance is not available');
        }

        return parent::load($id, $field);
    }
}
```

This in your concrete case does effectively prevent the error and will show you which model is missing. The rest I already answered exactly applies here. As this is resource related you could already assume that this is about the configuration of your resource model. But the better lesson to learn is to step through with a step debugger as the parsing of config files then will reveal which information is missing and more importantly why.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it the same error . And i make sure Model is available . Because when i echo get_class($blogpost) result is Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost . Please help me again . Thank you

Comment: @john: True, I haven't looked sharp enough on the error message. The model that is missing the load() method is the resource model the abstract model you extend from is missing. For that you have to check with getResourceModel() model first as you make indirect use of it.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added another example showing such a check. It was _getResource() and not getResourceModel but you could also check via Mage::getResourceModel()  IIRC.

Comment: Thank you very much :D . But when i apply your code and reload the page i have new problem "Error log record number: 418625702" and default skin magento . Can you run code in part 5 tutorial after that tell me why my code is error . I have just learned it too difficult for me . Thank you .

Comment: Sure in that case the Exception you just put in the checks is getting thrown. The page you see is a hint you do not have development mode enabled otherwise you would have seen the exception message directly. See this existing Q&A material: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/4115) - Also keep in mind that you have to look with a step-debugger. You should only guess  the first 1-3 minutes when debugging, after that, only follow hard facts, don't guess any longer.

Comment: Thank for your help but i can't fix it :( .

Comment: @john: So what prevents you from fixing it (just put it in simple words)?

Comment: I have just learned and i don't have experience in magento . So many code i dont understand , now i need sample project can run after that i start edit or remove some code and re-run project . That is my learning .

Comment: Okay, in short: The problem is with your resource model. Magento is not able to create it (Model uses the ResourceModel to load itself from the database) . This is why you have this "non-object" there in the error message. It means that an object could not be created. That object is the resource model in your case. As you fiddle with the configuration, double-check exactly that (resource-model related) part. You most likely are missing a tag there and/or have it misplaced. Compare with the tutorial, you should locate pretty fast where it differs.

Comment: Ok . Thank you very much . i have fixed that . :) . Have create day .

Comment: Great to read, you too!

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with the tutorial a lot but I have to say that it is a fantastic resource for Magento.

I think what you have missing is the following entry under your `<weblog>` section 
So,

```
<weblog>
  <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
  <resourceModel>weblog_resource</resourceModel
</weblog>
```

Try this and let me know if it solves your problem (if it is still a relevant issue for you :))